# How can I retrieve firebase hosting deploy ID or message inside my webapp?

Tags: firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

For logging purposes I´d like to print to console or even display the current deploy ID (or message) of my firebase web app that is being accessed by the browser.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting recently released a new [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest/). You can use [sites.releases.list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest/v1beta1/sites.releases/list) to see what version is currently deployed.

**Old answer:**

Firebase deploy IDs don't appear to be available anywhere via programmatic access. The [CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) doesn't support listing current or previous deploys.

My recommendation would be to go in the other direction. Have your source code in a vcs like git. When you build and deploy a new version set the vcs hash or version in the deployed code and as the message for `firebase deploy`. You can then log the log the source version in your code and you can manually associate that back to a release in the Firebase UI.